# How to add Header/Footer to with Google Docs API

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to add header and footer to an existing Google Docs file using [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/).

Looking at the `documents.batchUpdate` ([link](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#Request)) we can insert text, replace text, add images and table etc by mentioning them in the JSON payload with objects like `replaceAllText`, `insertText` etc but I cannot find any way to insert header and footer.

Question 1: How can I add header and footer?

Question 2: How can I add different header/footer for the first page of document?

If not possible, suggestion to use any other API or method (like using MS Word) will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

How about this answer?

### Question 1:

- You want to add the header and footer to Google Document.

About this question, how about the following flow?

#### Flow:

1. At first, it is required to manually open the header and footer in Google Document with your browser. By this, it seems that the header ID and footer ID can be created.

   - Even if the Document has only one page, when "Different first page" is checked, 2 ID s of 1st page and other pages are automatically created for the header and footer.

     - I think that this might be the current specification.
   - When the different sample texts for header and footer of 1st page and 2nd page are set, you can easily find the IDs.
2. As the next step, it retrieves the header ID and footer ID using the method of documents.get of Docs API. The endpoint is as follows.

   ```
    GET https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{documentId}?fields=footers%2Cheaders
   ```

   - From this result, the header ID and footer ID can be retrieved.
   - You can see 2 IDs for the header and footer.

     - When you manually set the text to the header and footer, if you checked "Different first page", each ID can be used for the 1st page and other pages except for 1st page. (This is the answer for your Question 2.)
3. It updates the header and footer using the method of documents.batchUpdate of Docs API. The endpoint and request body are as follows.

   ```
    POST https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{documentId}:batchUpdate

    {
     "requests": [
      {
       "insertText": {
        "location": {
         "segmentId": "kix.#####",
         "index": 1
        },
        "text": "sample text"
       }
      }
     ]
    }
   ```

   - `kix.#####` of `"segmentId": "kix.#####"` is the header ID and footer ID. By this, the text can be set.
   - `index` is the position of inserted text.

### Question 2:

- You want to know the method for setting the different values between 1st page and other pages.

About this question, how about the following flow?

#### Flow:

1. At first, it is required to manually open the header and footer in Google Document with your browser. By this, it seems that the header ID and footer ID can be created.

   - Even if the Document has only one page, when "Different first page" is checked, 2 ID s of 1st page and other pages are automatically created for the header and footer.
   - When the different sample texts for header and footer of 1st page and 2nd page are set, you can easily find the IDs.

After this, the flow is the same with the answer for Question 1.

### Note:

- When you request above endpoints, please use the access token retrieved by OAuth2 and Service account. And the please use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents` as the scope.
- About creating the IDs of header and footer, I have tried to do it to new Document using only API. But in the current stage, I couldn't achieve it yet. I apologize.

  - The current result is as follows. When the header and footer are added using Document Service with Google Apps Script, the IDs are not created. Only when the manually open the header and footer, the IDs are created.
  - From this result, in the current stage, I thought that this might be the specification.

### References:

- [documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [InsertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttextrequest)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Updated at January 1, 2022:

When I had answered this, the header and footer cannot be added using Google Docs API. In the current stage, these can be added using Google Docs API. I had a contact requesting to update this. So I added the method for adding the header and footer to Google Document using Google Docs API.

In the current stage, when you want to add the header and hooter to Google Document using Docs API, it seems that 2 API calls are required to be used because it seems that the header ID and footer ID cannot be manually given.

#### Flow (header):

##### 1. Create header.

The URL and request body is as follows.

```
POST https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{documentId}:batchUpdate

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "createHeader": {
        "sectionBreakLocation": {
          "index": 0
        },
        "type": "DEFAULT"
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

By this, the following response is returned.

```
{
  "replies": [
    {
      "createHeader": {
        "headerId": "kix.###"
      }
    }
  ],
  "writeControl": {
    "requiredRevisionId": "###"
  },
  "documentId": "###"
}
```

##### 2. Put text.

When you want to insert the text to the header, it uses `headerId` as follows.

```
POST https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{documentId}:batchUpdate

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertText": {
        "location": {
          "segmentId": "kix.###", <--- headerId
          "index": 0
        },
        "text": "sample text"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Flow (footer):

##### 1. Create header.

The URL and request body is as follows.

```
POST https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{documentId}:batchUpdate

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "createFooter": {
        "type": "DEFAULT"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

By this, the following response is returned.

```
{
  "replies": [
    {
      "createFooter": {
        "footerId": "kix.###"
      }
    }
  ],
  "writeControl": {
    "requiredRevisionId": "###"
  },
  "documentId": "###"
}
```

##### 2. Put text.

When you want to insert the text to the header, it uses `footerId` as follows.

```
POST https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{documentId}:batchUpdate

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "insertText": {
        "location": {
          "segmentId": "kix.###", <--- footerId
          "index": 0
        },
        "text": "sample text"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#### References:

- [CreateHeaderRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#createheaderrequest)
- [CreateFooterRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#createfooterrequest)

Comment: Thanks Tanaike. Do you know how to adjust "Header Margin"? I have added a SO question for the same - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57131446/change-header-margin-with-google-docs-api

Comment: @Slick Slime Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Can I ask you about the issue of my answer? By this, I would like to modify it. About your new question, after this your question was resolved, I would like to think of it. Because I cannot think both questions simultaneously. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: I still want to automatically create header and add content to it. And I cannot open the document on the browser in order to first create an empty header then manually check "Different first page" and then programmatically add content to the header - this will break the automation. Is there any way to resolve this? @Tanaike

Comment: @Slick Slime Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, in the current stage, only when the manually open the header and footer sections, the IDs are created. After the IDs were created, users can access to them using Docs API. It seems that this is the current specification. If you want to access to header and footer under the current situation, as the current workaround, I propose the method using Web Apps created by Google Apps Script. By this, you can use Web Apps as an API. By the way, I reported about this issue to the issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138042765

Comment: @SlickSlime: FYI, the latest Google Docs API provided a new request [CreateHeaderRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#CreateHeaderRequest). That can be used to create a new header. After creating a new header, you can add content using [InsertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttextrequest)

Comment: @Tanaike Where to put the URL `POST https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{documentId}:batchUpdate` in a python code as POST won't be supported there ? will it be the part of the requests body?

Comment: @Ask_Ashu I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your question, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help a lot of users including me think of the solution.

Comment: I'll post a new question but I just wanted to understand the significance of POST call here `POST https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/{documentId}:batchUpdate`? is it similar to `docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()` where `docs = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=credentials)`

Comment: @Ask_Ashu Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike, How can we apply "different first page" for footers in this? As you told, for different 1st page and other page footers, 2 footer Ids would be created but how to put it in the requests body?

Comment: @Ask_Ashu I would like to support you. Unfortunately, this is not your question. So, in order to answer your question, can you post it as a new question by including more information? And also, I think that your question will be useful for other users. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: sure, I'll post a new question

Comment: @Tanaike I am getting the response like you have shown above and also getting my footer id but can you tell me how to get it using "get" function.Because while appyling getFooterId() it throws error of  undefined method but i am getting my id in my response. When i print my response I can see that but how can i get it dynamically. Please help me with this. It would be a great help for me.

Comment: @Taniya Halder I think that your comment is the same with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71019154/how-we-can-insert-header-and-footer-in-google-docs-with-google-docs-api-using-ph/71019596?noredirect=1#comment125596285_71019596 Can you post your question as new question? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Tanaike thankyou for replying, I have posted a new question for your better understanding of the question  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71049383/how-can-we-get-headerid-and-footerid-from-the-response-we-get-after-batchupdate) Please help me out with this.