# Create google doc with footer

Tags: javascript, google-docs-api

I'm trying to create google doc with footer. But in response I've got only body

Here is my code with footer and title

```
gapi.client.docs.documents.create({
      "title": "Test document creating",
      "footers": {
        "footer.qwe": {
          "footerId": "footer.qwe",
          "content": [
            {
              "endIndex": 2,
              "paragraph": {
                "elements": [
                  {
                    "endIndex": 2,
                    "textRun": {
                      "content": "test\n",
                      "textStyle": {}
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "paragraphStyle": {
                  "namedStyleType": "NORMAL_TEXT",
                  "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
```

In response there is only empty body, without any footer element

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that that is a bug. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123897235 And also, because of this issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138042765 , the footer cannot be added after new Google Document was created. About this, you can also check it at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57120990).