# Is there a way to add headingId to paragraphs using Google Docs Api?

Tags: google-docs-api

**Problem**

If you edit a Google Doc and add TITLE's, HEADING_1's, HEADING_2's etc. and then perform a [documents.get request](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get), the JSON response contains headingId's.

Whereas if you use a [batchUpdate request](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request) with a [insertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttextrequest) and [updateParagraphStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updateparagraphstylerequest) (including, [namedStyleType](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#NamedStyleType) = HEADING_1) and then perform a [documents.get request](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get), the JSON response does not contain, headingId's.

I've tried sending the insertTextRequest in a separate batchUpdate request from the updateParagraphStyleRequest. I've also tried sending both together with the insertTextRequest first and last in the requests array as part of the batchUpdate request.

**documents.batchUpdate - Request Body:**

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "updateParagraphStyle": {
        "paragraphStyle": {
          "namedStyleType": "HEADING_1"
        },
        "range": {
          "segmentId": "",
          "startIndex": 1,
          "endIndex": 1
        },
        "fields": "namedStyleType"
      }
    },
    {
      "insertText": {
        "location": {
          "index": 1,
          "segmentId": ""
        },
        "text": "\nMyText\n"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**documents.get - Sample Output after the above batchUpdate request:**

```
{
        "startIndex": 2,
        "endIndex": 9,
        "paragraph": {
          "elements": [
            {
              "startIndex": 2,
              "endIndex": 9,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "MyText\n",
                "textStyle": {}
              }
            }
          ],
          "paragraphStyle": {
            "namedStyleType": "HEADING_1",
            "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT"
          }
        }
      },
```

**documents.get - Sample Output after manually editing the document:**

```
      {
        "startIndex": 2,
        "endIndex": 10,
        "paragraph": {
          "elements": [
            {
              "startIndex": 2,
              "endIndex": 10,
              "textRun": {
                "content": "My Text\n",
                "textStyle": {}
              }
            }
          ],
          "paragraphStyle": {
            "headingId": "h.3e6t9mhosaga",
            "namedStyleType": "HEADING_1",
            "direction": "LEFT_TO_RIGHT"
          }
        }
      },
```

In the documents.get request sample output after manually editing the document there is **"headingId": "h.3e6t9mhosaga",**.

Why isn't this `headingId` present after the batchUpdate request?

Comment: The similar situation also occurs when the header and footer are used at Docs API. https://stackoverflow.com/q/57113349/7108653 I think that this might be a bug. But Docs API is growing now. So these might be resolved in the future. But in the current stage, I apologize that your issue cannot be resolved soon.