# How to add header and footer in a google docx using google docs API in python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-api-python-client

I want to add footer in my google docs using google docs API in python which would be containing some Disclaimer as text and page number with auto incrementing feature. I'm not getting any good document to procced.

I'm trying the following sample approach for footers:

```
file_id = ####
def insert_data(file_id):
    requests = []
    index = 1
    requests.append(insert_text(index, '\n')) # function to insert text
    index += len('\n')
    requests.append(insert_image(index)) # function to insert image
    index += 1
    requests.append(insert_text(index, '\n')) # function to insert text
    index += len('\n')
    requests.append(insert_text(index, 'Hello googleAPI!')) # function to insert text
    index += len('Hello googleAPI!')
    requests.append(add_footer())

    docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()

def add_footer(requests, index):
    footer = {"CreateFooterRequest": {
        "description": "Creates a Footer. The new footer is applied to the SectionStyle at the location of the "
                       "SectionBreak if specificed, otherwise it is applied to the DocumentStyle. If a footer of the "
                       "specified type already exists, a 400 bad request error is returned.",
        "id": "CreateFooterRequest",
        "properties": {
            "sectionBreakLocation": {
                "$ref": "Location",
                "description": "The location of the SectionBreak immediately preceding the section whose SectionStyle "
                               "this footer should belong to. If this is unset or refers to the first section break "
                               "in the document, the footer applies to the document style. "
            },
            "type": {
                "description": "The type of footer to create.",
                "enum": [
                    "HEADER_FOOTER_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED",
                    "DEFAULT"
                ],
                "enumDescriptions": [
                    "The header/footer type is unspecified.",
                    "A default header/footer."
                ],
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "type": "object"
    }
    }
    return footer
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show your code?

Comment: Does this question on SO answer yours? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113349/how-to-add-header-footer-to-with-google-docs-api)