# how to add image in header and keep first page header and footer different from other pages using google docs API in python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-api-python-client

Thanks to [Tanaike's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113349/how-to-add-header-footer-to-with-google-docs-api), I'm able to add header and footer in my document. The only problem is I want to keep the first page's header and footer different from rest of the pages.

Also I want to add multiple small images in my header but using `insertInlineImage` in the header to add an image throws error.

My working code:

```
file_id = ##
def insert_data(file_id):
    requests = []
    header_footer_req = []

    index = 0
    header_footer_req.append(add_header(index))
    header_footer_req.append(add_footer())
    header_footer_res = docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': header_footer_req}).execute()
    header_id = header_footer_res['replies'][0]['createHeader']['headerId']
    footer_id = header_footer_res['replies'][1]['createFooter']['footerId']
    requests.append(add_header_content(index, header_id))
    requests.append(add_footer_content(footer_id))
    
    docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()    

def add_header(index):
    header = {
        "createHeader": {
            "sectionBreakLocation": {
                "index": index
            },
            "type": "DEFAULT"
        }
    }
    return header


def add_header_content(index, headerId):
    headerText = {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "segmentId": headerId,
                "index": index,
            },
            "text": "sample text"
        }
    }
    return headerText


def add_footer():
    footer = {
        "createFooter": {
            "type": "DEFAULT"
        }
    }
    return footer


def add_footer_content(footer_id):
    footer_data = {
        "insertText": {
            "location": {
                "segmentId": footer_id,
                "index": 0
            },
            "text": "This is my footer"
        }
    }
    return footer_data
```

Expected sample output:
Page 1:
[image: page 1]

Rest other pages:
[image: other pages]

Please note that the footer of both the pages are different and they are right aligned and are colored. It also has page number on the left.

Comment: When I saw your showing script, it seems that the script for `Also I want to add multiple small images in my header but using insertInlineImage in the header to add an image throws error.` is not included. Can you add it? And, in your goal, it seems that you want to use the different first page of header and footer. In your current script, the text is not put on the first page. Is this result what you want? In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample output situation as an image?

Comment: @Tanaike, I have added a sample response. I don't know what payload to use for alignment of images and texts in headers and footers.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. When I saw your updated question, it seems that your showing script for `Also I want to add multiple small images in my header but using insertInlineImage in the header to add an image throws error.` is not included. Can you add it? And, it seems that the texts in your sample images are different from your showing script. How about this? I'm confusing your goal from your sample image and your script. I would like to correctly understand your question. I apologize for this.

Comment: Now, I noticed that when a new Google Document is created and the header and footer are separated as the different first page, unfortunately, `firstPageHeaderId` and `firstPageFooterId` are not created. In this case, the text and image cannot be put to the 1st page header and footer. When the header and footer are manually created, those values are created. About this, how will you do? I thought that the reason for this might be that the header type is only one value of `DEFAULT`.

Comment: @Tanaike, so what happens when we put header/footer type as `HEADER_FOOTER_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED` instead of `DEFAULT`? How this will solve the problem?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, an error occurs. When you tested it, what result did you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike when I put header and footer type as `HEADER_FOOTER_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED`, I get an error `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1DOTbUHVq_IUG7HvaVZIvgmUO9J8O6vynH_KSsO6M2Gc:batc
hUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid requests[0].createHeader: Header type not specified.". Details: "Invalid requests[0].createHeader: Header type not speci
fied."`

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. I have the same issue. I thought that this might be the reason that `firstPageHeaderId` and `firstPageFooterId` cannot be created by Docs API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240745/discussion-between-ask-ashu-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to create a header and footer to Google Document.

  - From `I'll keep the header and footer in my document same for all the pages.`, you want to use the same header and footer for the 1st and other pages.
- For the header, you want to insert an image to the right side.
- For the footer, you want to insert 2 texts to the right side.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for python.

In this case, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, please modify your function of `insert_data` as follows.

```py
def insert_data(file_id):
    requests = []
    header_footer_req = []

    index = 0
    header_footer_req.append(add_header(index))
    header_footer_req.append(add_footer())
    header_footer_res = docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': header_footer_req}).execute()
    header_id = header_footer_res['replies'][0]['createHeader']['headerId']
    footer_id = header_footer_res['replies'][1]['createFooter']['footerId']

    # Add header content
    requests += [
        {
            "insertInlineImage": {
                "location": {
                    "segmentId": header_id,
                    "index": 0
                },
                "uri": "https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png", # This is a sample image.
                "objectSize": {
                    "width": {
                        "magnitude": 100,
                        "unit": "PT"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "updateParagraphStyle": {
                "paragraphStyle": {
                    "alignment": "END"
                },
                "range": {
                    "segmentId": header_id,
                    "startIndex": 0,
                    "endIndex": 1
                },
                "fields": "alignment"
            }
        }
    ]

    # Add footer content.
    text = "This is my footer\nsample text"
    requests += [
        {
            "insertText": {
                "location": {
                    "segmentId": footer_id,
                    "index": 0
                },
                "text": text
            }
        },
        {
            "updateParagraphStyle": {
                "paragraphStyle": {
                    "alignment": "END"
                },
                "range": {
                    "segmentId": footer_id,
                    "startIndex": 0,
                    "endIndex": len(text)
                },
                "fields": "alignment"
            }
        }
    ]

    docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

- If you want to align the content to the left side, please modify `END` to `START`.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, when the header and footer have already been created, an error like `Default header already exists.` occurs. Because the header and footer cannot be added to the Document which has the header and footer. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [InsertInlineImageRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#insertinlineimagerequest)
- [InsertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttextrequest)

Comment: Thank you so much @Tanaike. This works as expected.
Just one more question, what would be the alternate for `"uri"` field if I want to use image from my local pc?

Comment: @Ask_Ashu Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `what would be the alternate for "uri" field if I want to use image from my local pc?`, in this case, it is required to upload the image file to the site that can use the direct link. So in this case, I would like to recommend posting your new question as a new question.

Comment: Yes @Tanaike, I posted a new question regarding that.