# How can we apply "different first page" for footers in the google docs using google docs API and python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-api-python-client

@Tanaike already gave the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113349/how-to-add-header-footer-to-with-google-docs-api) to put header and footers in a google docs using google docs API.

```
file_id = ###

def insert_data(file_id):
    requests = []
    header_footer_req = []

    index = 0
    header_footer_req.append(add_header(index))
    header_footer_req.append(add_footer())
    header_footer_res = docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': header_footer_req}).execute()
    header_id = header_footer_res['replies'][0]['createHeader']['headerId']
    footer_id = header_footer_res['replies'][1]['createFooter']['footerId']
    # adding header and footer content

    requests += [
        {
            "insertInlineImage": {
                "location": {
                    "segmentId": header_id,
                    "index": 0
                },
                "uri": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1Nn-G6Y7jUlzYF3MPN_YlQC9Uasjdj33",
                # This is a sample image.
                "objectSize": {
                    "width": {
                        "magnitude": 100,
                        "unit": "PT"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "updateParagraphStyle": {
                "paragraphStyle": {
                    "alignment": "END"
                },
                "range": {
                    "segmentId": header_id,
                    "startIndex": 0,
                    "endIndex": 1
                },
                "fields": "alignment"
            }
        }
    ]

    # Add footer content.
    text = "This is my footer\nxyz"
    requests += [
        {
            "insertText": {
                "location": {
                    "segmentId": footer_id,
                    "index": 0
                },
                "text": text
            }
        },
        {
            "updateParagraphStyle": {
                "paragraphStyle": {
                    "alignment": "END"
                },
                "range": {
                    "segmentId": footer_id,
                    "startIndex": 0,
                    "endIndex": len(text)
                },
                "fields": "alignment"
            }
        }
    ]
    docs.documents().batchUpdate(documentId=file_id, body={'requests': requests}).execute()

def add_header(index):
    header = {
        "createHeader": {
            "sectionBreakLocation": {
                "index": index
            },
            "type": "DEFAULT"
        }
    }
    return header

def add_footer():
    footer = {
        "createFooter": {
            "type": "DEFAULT"
        }
    }
    return footer
```

1. The above code prints the same footer on every page. How can I have different footer on first page and other pages.

First page footer: `Disclaimer:  This is my test footer.`
Other pages footer: `@copyright reserved\nxyz.com`

2. How can I have page number as auto incremented on the right hand side of footer.
3. When I add an image in the header, the header size is increased, how can I make header size static on all the pages?

Comment: In the current stage, when a new Google Document is created and the header and footer are separated as the different first page using Docs API, unfortunately, `firstPageHeaderId` and `firstPageFooterId` are not created. In this case, the text and image cannot be put to the 1st-page header and footer. How do you want to do about this?

Comment: @Tanaike, so are you saying it's not possible to have different first page using google docs API? So, what about adding the page numbers?

Comment: Thank you for replying. It is possible to separate the 1st page and other pages of both header and footer. But, the text and image cannot be put to the header and footer of 1st page. Becausef `firstPageHeaderId` and `firstPageFooterId` are not created. I think that this might be due to only one header and footer type of `DEFAULT`. I apologize for this current situation.

Comment: So what I understood is, we can have separate first page and other pages but the first page's header and footer would be blank as we won't be having `firstPageHeaderId` and `firstPageFooterId` right?

Comment: Yes. I think that your understanding is correct. On the other hand, the header and footer except for 1st page can be managed by Docs API.

Comment: okay got it. I'll go with my current code as I need headers and footers on 1st page also but can we atleast have page numbers using google docs API?

Comment: About your 2nd question, unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, this cannot be also achieved by Docs API. I apologize for this.

Comment: About your 3rd question, the width and height of inserted image can be changed. I think that this might be the answer for your 3rd question.

Comment: @Tanaike, what changes should I make if I want to start headers and footers from the 2nd page, leaving 1st page blank?

Comment: I thought that in this case, it is required to show the request body. So I posted an answer including other answers. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

#### Question 1:

> Q1: The above code prints the same footer on every page. How can I have different footer on first page and other pages.

##### Answer:

In the current stage, when a new Google Document is created and the header and footer are separated as the different first page using Docs API, unfortunately, `firstPageHeaderId` and `firstPageFooterId` are not created. In this case, the text and image cannot be put to the 1st-page header and footer using Docs API. I think that this might be due to only one header and footer type of `DEFAULT`. On the other hand, the header and footer except for 1st page can be managed by Docs API.

When you want to set the different first page of header and footer, you can use the following request body.

```
{
  "updateDocumentStyle": {
    "documentStyle": {
      "useFirstPageHeaderFooter": True
    },
    "fields": "useFirstPageHeaderFooter"
  }
}
```

- When this request body is run, the 1st page of the header and footer is separated from other pages. But `firstPageHeaderId` and `firstPageFooterId` cannot be created. In the current stage, it seems that when you manually click the header and footer on Google Document, those values are created.
- When you want to manage the header and footer of another page except for 1st page, please use `defaultHeaderId` and `defaultFooterId` as `segmentId`.
- `True` of `"useFirstPageHeaderFooter": True` is for python.

#### Question 2:

> Q2: How can I have page number as auto incremented on the right hand side of footer.

##### Answer:

Unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, this cannot be also achieved by Docs API.

#### Question 3:

> Q3: When I add an image in the header, the header size is increased, how can I make header size static on all the pages?

##### Answer:

The width and height of the inserted image can be changed. I think that this might be the answer to your 3rd question. The sample request body is as follows.

```
{
  "insertInlineImage": {
    "uri": "###",
    "location": {
      "segmentId": "###",
      "index": 0
    },
    "objectSize": {
      "height": {
        "magnitude": 100, <--- Here, please set the size.
        "unit": "PT"
      },
      "width": {
        "magnitude": 100, <--- Here, please set the size.
        "unit": "PT"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [UpdateDocumentStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatedocumentstylerequest)
- [InsertInlineImageRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#insertinlineimagerequest)
- [Size](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#Size)