# How we can insert header and footer in google docs with google docs api using PHP code

Tags: php, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to insert header and footer in my google docs with google docs api in PHP code. I am doing it like this-

```
$requests = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
            'createHeader' => [
                'type' => 'TITLE',
                'sectionBreakLocation' => [
                    'index' => 0
            ],
        ],
    )),
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
    'requests' => $requests
));

$response = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

but, i am getting this error-

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid value at 'requests[5].create_header.type' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.docs.v1.HeaderFooterType), \"TITLE\"",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid value at 'requests[5].create_header.type' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.docs.v1.HeaderFooterType), \"TITLE\"",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "requests[5].create_header.type",
            "description": "Invalid value at 'requests[5].create_header.type' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.docs.v1.HeaderFooterType), \"TITLE\""
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help me out with this, That how we can insert texts in header and footer in google docs using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Create header:

I thought that the reason of the error message of `Invalid value at 'requests[5].create_header.type' (type.googleapis.com/google.apps.docs.v1.HeaderFooterType), \"TITLE\""` is due to `'type' => 'TITLE',`. But when I saw your script, `$requests` is required to be an array. So how about the following modification?

##### From:

```
$requests = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
            'createHeader' => [
                'type' => 'TITLE',
                'sectionBreakLocation' => [
                    'index' => 0
            ],
        ],
    )),
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
    'requests' => $requests
));
```

##### To:

```
$requests = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
    'createHeader' => [
        'type' => 'DEFAULT',
        'sectionBreakLocation' => [
            'index' => 0
        ],
    ],
));

$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
    'requests' => array($requests)
));
```

#### Create footer:

In this case, please replace `createHeader` to `createFooter` in the above `$requests`.

#### Note:

- As additional information, when you want to use the first page header and footer, you can use the following request.

  ```
    $requests = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
        'updateDocumentStyle' => [
            'documentStyle' => [
                'useFirstPageHeaderFooter' => true,
            ],
            'fields' => 'useFirstPageHeaderFooter',
        ],
    ));
  ```

#### References:

- [CreateHeaderRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#createheaderrequest)
- [CreateFooterRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#createfooterrequest)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but can I ask how we can insert text in header and footer for the same above requests.

Comment: @Taniya Halder Thank you for replying. About your new question of `but can I ask how we can insert text in header and footer for the same above requests.`, when `createHeader` and `createFooter` are used, the header ID and footer ID are created. Using these IDs, you can insert the text to the header and footer using [InsertTextRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttextrequest). In this case, please use the header ID and the footer ID to `segmentId` of `location`. By this, you can insert the text to the header and footer.

Comment: how we can get headerId and footerId, i am doing it but unable to get it.Please help me through this .I am literally stuck on this part.It would be a great help.

Comment: @Taniya Halder Thank you for replying. About your new question of `how we can get headerId and footerId`, in this case, when the header and footer are created for the 1st time, you can retrieve the header ID and footer ID can be retrieved from the returned value from the batchUpdate method. When the header and footer have already been existing, you can retrieve the header ID and footer ID can be retrieved by the get method. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)

Comment: @Taniya Halder But your new question is different from your this question. If you want the sample script, can you post it as a new question? Because when you post it as a new question, I thought that your new question is important for other users. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: I am getting the response like you have shown above and also getting my footer id but can you tell me how to get it using "get" function.Because while appyling getFooterId() it throws error of undefined method but i am getting my id in my response. When i print my response I can see that but how can i get it dynamically. Please help me with this. It would be a great help for me.

Comment: @Taniya Halder Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot correctly imagine your current script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you post it as new question? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it? I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.