# How can we get HeaderId and FooterId from the response we get after batchUpdate request in google docs api using PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am working on google docs api. I want to insert text into header and footer simultaneously and for that I need header/footer id. So, for that I firstly created header/footer like this-

```
$requests[] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
  "createFooter" => [
    "sectionBreakLocation" => [
      "index" => 0,
      "segmentId" => "1",
    ],
    "type" => "DEFAULT",
  ],
));

$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(array(
    'requests' => $requests
));

$response = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

After this, when I print my $response using print_r($response), I can see my footer id.Like this -

```
                    [createFooter] => Google\Service\Docs\CreateFooterResponse Object
                        (
                            [footerId] => kix.vv5nq4qsqioo
                            [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [modelData:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [processed:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )
```

but,after this I am unable to get my footer id dynamically. How I can fetch my footer id from this response using PHP.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `dynamically`? The footerId is always contained in the response `replies.createFooter.fiiterId`

Comment: yes, but how we can fetch it from this replies.createFooter.footerId  ? is there any method to fetch this.If there is then how we can fetch that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just access the `footerId` from the response:

```php
$response = $service->documents->batchUpdate($documentId, $batchUpdateRequest);
$footerId = $response->replies[0]->createFooter->footerId;
print($footerId);
```

#### Ref:

- [PHP: Objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php)
- [PHP: Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help, I am able to get the ids now. But, can you tell me, If I once updated my batch request to get the ids from response, Can i again make batch update to insert text in header using the index location as header Id.

Comment: Insert index and header ID aren’t the same thing and can’t be used interchangeably - might be best to ask a new question for a more in depth answer though :)

Comment: I have posted it as a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052930/how-can-we-insert-text-into-header-footer-after-creating-header-footer-in-google).It would be a great help if you can help me out with this query.